# A difficulty in understanding the solution of 8.3.2 Petrovic.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question is asking about the set $A$ of values of $x$ for which the following series converges pointwise:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x + n)(x+n-1)} $$

A part of the answer is given below:

[image]

But I do not know why he defined the set A to be like this, could anyone explain this for me please?

Also I can see that the answer is dealing with the following series instead:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x + n)(x+ n + 1)} $$

Will this affect the value of $x$ and is this value of $x$ applicable for the first series I mentioned above?

**EDIT:**

I think there is a typo and the set A should not contain $\pi$ ....... am I correct?

Comment: the values of $x$ for which the following series converges pointwise???? what does "pointwise" mean? Do you mean "the values of $x$ for which the following series converges"?

Comment: I am saying this because the rest of the question asks if the convergence is uniform on A or not@mathworker21

Comment: The terms of the sum are well defined when they do not have 0 in the denominator. So as you suggested, the $\pi$ is just a typo.

Comment: There are two typos in the same problem taken from the book !